# How do I perform a unit test on a delayed function?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, underscore.js

I am implementing [_.delay](http://underscorejs.org/#delay) and I was to write a unit test for it. I have no idea how to do this though, since the test would need to account for the time delay. Is this possible? I am using Jasmine for my testing suite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Sinon.js](http://sinonjs.org/) allows you to create [fake timers](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#clock) for these kinds of cases. You create a fake timer (which overrides the global timers), do whatever set-up you need, tick the fake timer forward by however much you need, and then check your results.